# OTP integration at registration form

Tags: php, html, one-time-password

I am having trouble integrating the "send OTP" function in my registration form. I was given an API from an SMS provider, but I do not know how to integrate it into my form. I need the user data to be recorded in my database after the verify the OTP. But how the verify process work? and how does the system would generate 6 digits random code to the user? I have been trying a different method and search online but none of that is working. Can anyone help?

Here is my form:

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST" class="p-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="uid" required="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name1" class="col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dob" name="dob" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="c_pass" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Are You Previously an  Existing Member?</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="recipient-name10" name="member">
                            <option>Yes</option>
                            <option>No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Where do you know about this membership?</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="recipient-name11" name="outlet">
                            <option>The Metallic Kitchen @ Golden Triangle Pelangi, JB</option>
                            <option>The Metallic Kitchen @ Taman Mount Austin, JB</option>
                            <option>The Metallic Kitchen & Bar @ Setapak Village, KL</option>
                            <option>None of the above</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">OTP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="OTP" name="otp" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-w3l mt-4 mb-3">
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Create account" name="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
```

and here is my sms provider API:

```
<?php 
    function sendSmsToEsms() {
        $url = 'https://api.esms.com.my/sms/send';

        // replace yourusername, yourpassword, and 60123456789 to suits your need
        $data = array('user' => 'yourusername', 
            'pass' => 'yourpassword', 
            'to' => '60123456789', 
            'msg' => 'RM0.00 Hello from ESMS');

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

        var_dump($result);
    }
?>
```

here is my code for adding data into database:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include_once 'db.php';

        $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['first']);
        $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['last']);
        $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uid']);
        $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['dob']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
        $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['m_number']);
        $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pass']);
        $member =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['member']);
        $outlet = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['outlet']);

//ERROR HANDLERS
//CHECK FOR EMPTY FIELDS
        //if(empty($first)||empty($last)||empty($uid)||empty($dob)||empty($email)||empty($mobile)||empty($pwd)||empty($member)||empty($outlet))
            //{
                //header("Location:../index.php?signup=empty");
                //exit();
        //}else{
            //check if input characters are valid
            //if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first)|| !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)){
                //header("Location:../signup.php?signup=invalid");
                //exit();
            //}else{
                //check email 
                if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    echo "<script>alert('Invalid Email,please register again.')</script>";
                        echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
                        exit();
                }else{
                    //check if username is same
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid'";
                    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

                    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Username has been taken, please register again.')</script>";
                        echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
                        exit();
                    }else{
                        //Hashing pwd
                        $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        //INSERT THE USER INTO THE DATABASE
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first,user_last,user_uid,user_dob,user_email,user_mobile,user_pwd,user_member,user_outlet) VALUES ('$first','$last','$uid','$dob','$email','$mobile','$hashedPwd','$member','$outlet');";
                        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        echo "<script>alert('You have been Registered Successfully, Please login from our main page')</script>";
                        echo "<script>window.open('../index.php','_self')</script>";
                        exit();

                    }
                }
            }



else{
    header("Location:../index.php");
    exit();
}


?>
```

Comment: Where is your code checking the form was posted?

Comment: As I can see you've to replace user and pass with yours from the provider, to is the client number, and msg the message you would like to receive. What 6 digit number are you talking about?

Comment: i have updated the code @delboy1978uk

Comment: the six-digit number I am talking about is when key in their phone number, there will be a random six-digit code generate by the system and sent to the user's phone number in order to verify their phone number is correct, but I am stuck on how to generate it and how to verify it.@D.Dimitrov

Answer (score 0):

You should temporarily save user data into database as well as the generated OTP and also an extra column to indicate if user is validated. (I suggest to hash OTP before saving).

Later when the user tries the username and OTP for login, you should check entered data against the database. If user and OTP are correct, check that column to validate the registration. If OTP is incorrect you can leave that column for more tries (or delete user account or void the OTP or regenerate a new OTP bases on your opinion).

to generate a random number use mt_rand algorythm:

```
$password=mt_rand (10,100);
```

and use it in API as follow:

```
'pass' => $password,
```

Comment: but What I am trying to achieve is :
First: the user register at my form
Second: at the same form beside the phone number box has a send otp button and when it clicked , an otp will sent to users phone
Third :the user key in the otp and clicked submit and all the data will be recorded at my database

Comment: You should not make the OTP session based because the user may loose the session for many reasons. The standard way is to save first form temporary and look forward for OTP check to decide to delete or confirm those temporary data @louis